Permanently set cgroup setting for user slice
I am setting the cgroups for user.slice as per the below command through executing the script whenever user is login and this script is getting executed from /etc/pam.d/ssh
systemctl set-property user-$uid.slice CPUAccounting=true CPUQuota=10% MemoryAccounting=true MemoryLimit=150M
But, I can see that setting is getting override from the user if they are running the same command from there shell with different values .
Is there a way for a permanently fix this , so it doesn't get override ?
OR is there any other way to apply the resource limit for user slice
Centos 7.3
systemd version 213
cgroups:- v1

How come your users have permissions to run systemctl set-property, though? Did you give them sudo privileges or something? Can you show the syslog (journalctl -f) messages from after having a user run this command?

No , they don't have I am doing some tests with my account on my test machine for cgroup implementation , and looking for any other way for cgroup implementation like dropin concept

Then I'm not sure I understand what the issue is? If the users cannot run the same command from their shell with different values, how are they overriding anything?
